# Country code switches after trying to connect to a router

Tags: network, wifi, mojave

I have a 13-inch MacBook Air (late 2015) on Mojave 10.14.6.
Whenever I boot up the laptop, it starts with the correct country code (CA), (below is my diagnostic info before attempting to connect to the network)

[image: Diagnostic info before attempting to connect]

While attempting to connect to the network, the country code remains CA. Despite this, my laptop then fails to connect to the network, and the country code switches from CA to X0. After doing a scan, there are no routers in the area with the X0 country code, but there is one with the US code.

[image: Network Diagnostic info after attempting to connect]

I have not been able to connect to the network since. The problem seemingly came out of nowhere as there were no issues yesterday.

Comment: What steps did you do already to troubleshoot? What is the country code of your router in the WiFi scan? What type of router is it? Did maybe the router perform an upgrade silently in the backkround overnight? Have you tried power-cycling everything?